# Add a layer of paths on whole map

Tags: android, here-api

I use here-map sdk. I have db file with 16500 ! paths (coordinates of a point). I need to draw all paths on the map, when user activate function "show additional paths". But i think, if i try to fetch big number of path and add all poplilynes object on here map, it will take a huge amount of time.

Help to find the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter your data based on the visible viewport and disable this functionality where it doesn't make much sense (continental or globe level).

So, let's assume you app shows the map on zoomlevel 16 or 17 (district level), you can retrieve the viewport as GeoBoundingBox from the Map instance (e.g. via mapView.getMap()) with getBoundingBox().
The GeoBoundingBox makes it easy for you now to check for collisions with your own objects, since it has several "contains()" methods.

So everything that collides with your viewport should be shown, everything else is ignored.

You can update whenever the map viewport changes with either listening for OnTransformListener in the Map class or register for the MapGesture events (get MapGesture via getMapGesture() and listen for zooming events via addOnGestureListener())

If the amount of data for filtering is still too big, you can also think about preparing your data for more efficient filtering, like partitioning (region based would be my first idea) so only a subset of your data needs to be filtered.

Comment: thank you, this is the best solution. I will try to implement this process

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Custom Location Extension (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/custom-location/topics/what-is.html) can help with this case.
In short, it allows you to upload a custom data to the HERE backend and query it later.